# Selenium Webdriver - Java - How to get all values of excel and store in Array?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Can any of you please help me with the code for this? I would like to store all values from excel into Array and then use those values in my code

For Example -

Row 1-3 - Should perform some action 
Row 4-6 - Should perform some action
Row 7-9 - Should perform some action

[Question Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T23Zw.png)

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the excel sheet and also the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Sudharsan, I attached screenshot as requested. I'm new to Selenium so I haven't tried Array List so far (Sorry I don't have code). Appreciate your help!!

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there for this. Please read them and try to code it yourself. If you still have problems, come back and edit your question... post your code and any error messages you are getting or why it isn't working. SO is not a "write this code for me" site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowIterator` and `cellIterator` to loop through entire document and store the values in a seperate 2D array.have a look at below example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList<String[]> rowsFromExcel = readContentFromExcel();
   for(int i=0;i<rowsFromExcel.size();i++){  //For each rows in excel
      for(int j=0;i<rowsFromExcel.get(i).length;i++){ //For each cell in that row
        System.out.print(rowsFromExcel.get(i)[j]);
      }
   }
}

public static ArrayList<String[]> readContentFromExcel(){
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("pathToFile\\filename.xls"));
    int columnCount = 13; // i have taken the column count form your screenshot.
    ArrayList<String[]> ExcelRows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    int cellIndex = 0;
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
      Row row = rowIterator.next();
      Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
      String[] cellValues  = new String[columnCount];
      while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
           Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
           cellValues[cellIndex++] = cell.getStringCellValue();
           System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
      }
     ExcelRows.add(cellValues);
     cellIndex=0;
   }

  file.close();
  return ExcelRows;
}
```

Comment: Why not just do a for-each loop? See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

Comment: I agree!! using for-each will reduce length of the code and will be more readable!!